# Pass soap value programatically using php

Tags: php, curl, soap

I had the following php script to update the xml value:

```
//The XML string that you want to send.
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<reminder>
    <date>2019-20-02T10:45:00</date>
    <heading>Meeting</heading>
    <body>Team meeting in Boardroom 2A.</body>
</reminder>';


//The URL that you want to send your XML to.
$url = 'http://localhost/xml';

//Initiate cURL
$curl = curl_init($url);

//Set the Content-Type to text/xml.
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: text/xml"));

//Set CURLOPT_POST to true to send a POST request.
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);

//Attach the XML string to the body of our request.
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);

//Tell cURL that we want the response to be returned as
//a string instead of being dumped to the output.
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

//Execute the POST request and send our XML.
$result = curl_exec($curl);

//Do some basic error checking.
if(curl_errno($curl)){
    throw new Exception(curl_error($curl));
}

//Close the cURL handle.
curl_close($curl);

//Print out the response output.
echo $result;
```

But, what i plan to do is, I want to make the $xml using dynamic value, has been try something like this:

```
$date= $_POST['datevalue'];
$heading= $_POST['meetingvalue'];
$body= $_POST['bodycontent'];

$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<reminder>
    <date>{$date}</date>
    <heading>{$date}</heading>
    <body>{$date}</body>
</reminder>';
```

Unfortunately the above code not working, seem the {$date} did not send nothing to rest SOAP.

Anyone has experience how to solve this,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not an expert in this, so just giving a suggestion, 
try using double quotes as below :

```
$xml = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>
<reminder>
  <date>{$date}</date>
  <heading>{$date}</heading>
  <body>{$date}</body>
</reminder>";
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

What about replacing strings?

```
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <reminder>
        <date>%s</date>
        <heading>%s</heading>
        <body>%s</body>
    </reminder>';

$message = sprintf($xml, $date, $heading, $body);
```

Anyway a complete dynamic XML aproach could be using the DomDocument class.

```
$doc = new DomDocument('1.0', 'iso-8859-1');
$reminder = $doc->createElement('reminder');

$date = $doc->createElement('date', $dateValue);
$reminder->appendChild($date);

$heading = $doc->createElement('heading', $headingValue);
$reminder->appendChild($heading);

$body = $doc->createElement('body', $bodyValue);
$reminder->appendChild($body);

$doc->appendChild($reminder);
$xmlString = $doc->saveXML();
```

The `$xmlString` variable contains your xml tree as a string with your dynamic values.